# Finding the expected value of $\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}$ where X is binomial

Tags: probability, statistics

So i was trying to solve one of late questions from past midterms and had that:

Find E($\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}$) where $X∼b(n,p)$

i know i can solve the sum of g(x)f(x) but i got stuck in solving that one

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PGF of $X$ is $\Bbb Et^X=(q+pt)^n$ with $q:=1-p$. Integrating from $0$ to $t$ twice, $\Bbb E\frac{t^{X+1}}{X+1}=\frac{(q+pt)^{n+1}-q^{n+1}}{p(n+1)}$ and $\Bbb E\frac{t^{X+2}}{(X+1)(X+2)}=\frac{(q+pt)^{n+2}-q^{n+2}}{p^2(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{q^{n+1}t}{p(n+1)}$. Setting $t=1$, $\Bbb E\frac{1}{(X+1)(X+2)}=\frac{1-q^{n+2}}{p^2(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{q^{n+1}}{p(n+1)}$.

Comment: Yeah i think its the correct answer can you solve it with the sum solution without the probability generating function?

Comment: @TeMPeL You coild try$$\sum_{x=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{x}p^xq^{n-x}}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\int_0^1dy\int_0^1dzq^n\sum_x\binom{n}{x}\left(\frac{pyz}{q}\right)^xz=\int_0^1dy\int_0^1dz(q+pyz)^nz.$$